# Confused about how to set up OpenSSL for UDK2018

Tags: openssl, uefi, edk2

I'm trying to set up a UDK2018 environment. Step 3 of the instructions refers to a text file in the OpenSSl with instructions below, but then says to download a zip and extract it. None of the commands in the instructions seem to work, because the directory isn't a git depository. I'm not very experienced at this, just trying to develop a UEFI script for a test. Any help on how to set up the environment would be great. Here are the instructions from the text file I referred to above:

## "HOW to Install OpenSSL for UEFI Building

OpenSSL repository was added as one submodule of EDKII project.

The user can use the following commands to clone both main EDKII repo and
openssl submodule:
  1) Add the "--recursive" flag to the git clone command:
     $ git clone --recursive https://github.com/tianocore/edk2
or
  2) Manually initialize and update the submodules after the clone operation
     on main project:
     $ git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2
     $ git submodule update --init --recursive

And use the following combined commands to pull the remote submodule updates
(e.g. Updating the new supported OpenSSL release tag):
     $ git pull --recurse-submodules && \
       git submodule update --recursive --remote"

Thank you,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the UDK release by cloning the [abovementioned github repository](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UDK2018) and checking out the `UDK2018` branch. That will give you the submodule metadata, and make the above instructions work.

**Note:** this branch contains backported fixes above what was in the original UDK2018 release. The original released version can be obtained as the `vUDK2018` tag.
[More information.](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UDK2018)